# Извлечение значений из нескольких инпутов

Tags: php, javascript

Есть форма с полями:

```
<input value='' name="question" id="question"  class="form-
  control" placeholder="q">

<input value='' name="answer" id="answer" class="form-control"
  placeholder="a">
```

Также есть возможность добавлять поля динамически:

```
var inputQ = $('<input/>', {
        type: 'text',
        name: 'DynamicExtraField[]',
        placeholder: 'Вопрос',
        value: '',
        class: 'form-control'
    }).appendTo(div);

var inputA = $('<input/>', {
        type: 'text',
        name: 'DynamicExtraField[]',
        placeholder: 'Ответ',
        value: '',
        class: 'form-control',
        }).appendTo(div);
```

Как мне теперь получить значение каждого поля? Я так понимаю, что все значения нужно добавить в массив и потом на сервере обработать этот массив. Как мне добавить значение полей в массив? Например, если у элемента уникальный идентификатор, то можно сделать так:

```
 var question= $('#question').val();
```

Но в моем случае много элементов с одинаковым идентификатором.

Comment: Вопрос не понятный

Comment: изучите `php`, `ajax`

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan, могу объяснить. Что конкретно не понятно? Я знаю что нужно ajax использовать. Вопрос в том, как мне собрать эти данные в массив, а как их дальше обрабатывать я знаю

Comment: Добавьте код которым вы отправляете данные из формы на сервер

Comment: Вместо обяснения конкретно мне или кому то давайте подробно опишите что делаете и какая часть не получается

Comment: Почти такой же вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/693495

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать циклом через form.elements:

```
var formValuesArray = [];
for(var i = 0;i<form.elements.length;i++){
  formValuesArray.push(form.elements[i].value); //Или то что нужно
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В качестве атрибута `name` используйте не `question`, а `question[]`. Аналогично с другими полями, которые являются множественными.

Теперь все такие поля будут приходить на сервер массивами (есть не с помощью ajax делать).

Если делать с помощью ajax, то проще всего воспользоваться jQuery функцией serializeArray. Она собирает данные из формы в массив ключ:значение.

Пример использования с Post запросом:

```
$.post(
  "Url",
  $("#myForm").serializeArray();
  onCompleteCallback
);
```

Comment: Вроде все работает, но результат приходит не в том виде. `array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(10) "question[]" ["value"]=> string(3) "que" } [1]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(8) "answer[]" ["value"]=> string(3) "ans" } }`. Т.е. как два элемента, а нужно чтобы было типа: `{"question" => "que", "answer"=>"ans"}`. чтобы можно было их обрабатывать в одном цикле

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно `<input/>` элементы обернуть в тег `<form/>` с атрибутами `action` и `method`, где `action` - это ссылка на файл на сервере, который будет обрабатывать данные из формы, а `method` - это метод отправки. Подробнее Вы можете почитать [тут](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp). Так же нужен дополнительный `<input/>` элемент для генерации события отправки с атрибутом `type` и значением `submit`.
При нажатии на кнопку `submit` все `<input/>` элементы, которые находятся внутри формы, будут отправлены на сервер по адресу который указан в атрибуте `action`, и записаны в суперглобальный массив [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.post.php). Из него то и можно получить все данные.

HTML

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="index.php">

  <input value='' name="question" id="question"  class="form-
  control" placeholder="q">

  <input value='' name="answer" id="answer" class="form-control"
   placeholder="a">

  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">

</form>
```

В JS файле пишем такой код:

```
// Устанавливаем обработчик событий submit на форму
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    // Отменяем действие по умолчанию.(отправка формы)
    e.preventDefault();

    // Записываем данные формы в переменную
    var formData = new FormData( $(this).get(0) );

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function(responce){
            alert(responce);
        },
        error: function(responce){
            alert(responce); 
        }
});
```

После чего в файле обработчике, в нашем случае `index.php` , нужно соединиться с базой данных, после чего записать данные из массива пришедшего на сервер. Это довольно обширный вопрос, так как Вы не указали базу данных, которую используете, но представим, что у Вас mysql. И для универсальности будем использовать [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php). С помощью нижеприведенного кода Вы подключитесь к базе, соответственно указав свои данные.

PHP

```
 $host = "localhost";
 $db = "test";
 $user = "root";
 $password = '12345';

 $data_base = new PDO ("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db","$user","$password" );

 $data_base->exec("set names utf8");
 $data_base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Затем нужно записать из массива [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.post.php), в котором то и хранятся данные, которые были переданы из формы. Делается это следующим образом: (Cледует упомянуть о [подготавливаемых запросах](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php))

```
// Подготавливаем запрос
$result = $data_base->prepare("
        INSERT INTO `table` (question, answer)
        VALUES (?, ?)
    ");
// Выполняем запрос
$result->execute( array(
    $_POST['question'],
    $_POST['answer']
) );

// Если произошла ошибка, уведомляем
if ( !$result ) {
   echo 'Error!';
   break;   
}
```