# Добавление элементов в массив с помощью .serializeArray()

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте. Имеется форма с полями:

```
   var inputQ = $('<input/>', {
        type: 'text',
        name: 'question[]',
        placeholder: 'Вопрос',
        value: '',
        class: 'form-control',
        id:'question[]'
    }).appendTo(div);

    var inputA = $('<input/>', {
        type: 'text',
        name: 'answer[]',
        placeholder: 'Ответ',
        value: '',
        class: 'form-control',
        id:'answer[]'
        }).appendTo(div);
```

Получаю значение полей и обрабатываю их:

```
    var arr = ($("#myForm").serializeArray());
             $.ajax({
                  ....
                 data: {action: 'addQuestionDB', 'arr': arr},
                  ....
             });
```

Проблема в том что массив приходить в виде:

```
          {'первый инпут', 'значение первого инпута'}, {'второй инпут', 'значение второго инпута'}.
```

А надо чтобы было так:

```
          {'первый инпут', 'значение первого инпута', 'второй инпут', 'значение второго инпута'}.
```

Comment: Может назвать поля одинаково, например 'question[]'?

Comment: А зачем такая структура? Выглядит странно и нелогично, не проще ли код написать так, чтобы вас устраивала структура массива? На мой взгляд, это будет более верным решением.

Comment: @Stanislav Belichenko, что именно вы считаете нелогичным?

Comment: @Ivan Bolnikh, не работает(

Comment: То, что вам зачем-то нужна такая структура для обработки этих значений. В чем логика, что за код требует такой структуры?

Comment: @Stanislav Belichenko, для динамического добавления полей

Comment: Извините, но ни из кода, ни из ваших объяснений ничего непонятно. Поясните  в вопросе, откуда и куда идут данные, как их принимает или отправляет код на стороне бекенда, тогда станет яснее.

Answer (score 1):

Странная, конечно, потребность в такой структуре, но

```
$.fn.serializeAnotherArray = function(){
    var arr = $(this).serializeArray(),b=[],c=[];
    $.each(arr,function(){
        c.push(this.name.replace('[]',''),this.value);
        if(c.length==4){
            b.push(c);
            c = [];
        }
    });
    return b;
}
```

Вызов будет такой

```
var arr = $("#myForm").serializeAnotherArray();
```

Comment: вроде работает. Сейчас попробую. А что именно вас смущает? То что поля динамически добавляются или что?

Comment: Нет все таки работает не так как нужно

Comment: @r.mcreal мне просто не понятно зачем уходить от достоверности? Параметр:значение. Лучшее сочетание для чтения данных. Это мое мнение.

Comment: В ответе массив ['имя инпута','значение этого инпута','имя другого инпута','значение другого инпута']

Comment: прошу прощения, видимо я непонятно объясняю. У меня значение двух инпутов должны быть в одном объекте. Результат должен быть таким: `['question' ,'значение этого инпута','answer','значение другого инпута'] , ['question' ,'значение этого инпута','answer','значение другого инпута'] `. И так далее, чтобы значение полей `question` и `answer` обрабатывать в одном цикле

Comment: поправил в ответе

Comment: Спасибо! Все как надо) Но теперь возник другой вопрос, как получить значения на стороне сервера? Раньше получал так: `$arr = array();
        $arr = $_POST['arr'];

        for($i = 0; $i<count($arr); $i++)
      {
            echo $arr[$i]['name'] ;}

Comment: все разобрался. Спасибо!